# Understanding instance hours on the Google Cloud Platform

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

On the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) my Java app is running on the Standard App Engine (GAE). Yesterday I deployed the app. As the only user of the app (until it goes live), I noticed that the startup time (a.k.a "warmup") took on the order of between 15 and 30 seconds when the first request was made. If I continued to make requests every few seconds, the response time was fast (around a second or less). But if I made no request after about 10 seconds, the next request took the usual 15 to 30 seconds to return. This told me that GAE was recognizing idle time of more than 10 seconds and decided to terminate the instance.

Of course this is bad. Even when the app does go live, initially there will be only a small number of users and the time between requests will certainly be longer than 10 seconds.

I decided to add some code to the app to keep each microservice alive. I did this by creating a task in the task queue that would call a method that in turn would do HTTP calls on each microservice. These were dummy methods in each service but they forced Java to load the classes. After all HTTP calls were made, I would then wait 5 seconds and then put another task in the queue and repeat the same process. This worked. I noticed that I no longer saw 15 to 30 second warmup times.

I started the app late in the afternoon and let it run overnight to see what the response would be the next morning. The next morning I noticed that the response was fast although not quite as fast as it was previously. But then about an hour later, I was totally surprised when suddenly I got that horrible "Quota reached" response and the app was no longer available.

I then checked my billing and noticed that I had incurred $1.50. Yet my budget is set to $100. So why would my quota be reached and the app stop accepting requests? After all, even if I had reached the quota, my budget was still set for $100 and the lowest alert threshold was set to 50%.

I then looked at my billing and saw the following:

Frontend: 2,857.24 Minutes ($1.03)
Backend: 574.99 Minute ($0.03)

So 2,857 in hours is about 47. Since they give you 28 hours for free, that meant I was billed for about 20 hours. 20 times $0.05 is around $1.00 which is what I am seeing.

So why am I using 47 hours when the app had been running for around 12 hours? One possible reason is that GAE starts up multiple instances. Unfortunately I didn't look on the Instances page to see how many instances it used and since it resets it each day, I can't know.

If my "keep alive" code was keeping the instance alive every 5 seconds, why would GAE even bother to startup another instance? I mean, requests at 5 second intervals is pretty long. That should in no way give the GAE algorithm some indication that the instance was under heavy use and needed to fire up another instance.

I decided to deactivate my "keep alive" code and make a setting in GAE that limits the number of instances to one but I also chose to have a minimum number of instances set to one as well. I assume that this will keep the instance alive and handle all my requests and that the daily 28 hours would never max out. Or have I misunderstood how these instance hours work?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question for Google Customer Service.

Comment: You have to examine specific settings, consider providing your App YAML file, specially since all the explanation is lacking what type of scaling you're using (automatic, basic, manual) and what options have you specified for scaling (min_instances, target_cpu_utilization, target_throughput_utilization, min_idle_instances, idle_timeout, etc).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GAE instance hours a lot more than real hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51856272/gae-instance-hours-a-lot-more-than-real-hours) and [Possible to have a single instance running 24 hours and not use the free 28 hours on GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51874615/possible-to-have-a-single-instance-running-24-hours-and-not-use-the-free-28-hour)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the 47 instance hours question, there are a few factor controlling instance usage cost:

1) Instance size. The bigger instances are counted in multiplier of the smallest instances - so a F2 for an hour is the same as a F1 for 2 hours.

2) If you are scaling up and down with automatic scaling, sometimes multiple instances can be started up if your request suddenly spikes. It will take 15 minutes of idling to turn down the instance.

3) Each service has its own instances

So basically, don't rely on your traffic pattern to keep your cost consistent. If you need stricter control, you can either use [manually scaled instances](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-instances-are-managed#instance_scaling) or [max-instances configuration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#scaling_elements)

As for your quota issue, we would need the error message to see which quota you are hitting, there's no "instance hour" quota so you are probably hitting something else. Quota and budgets are independent concepts, even if you have unlimited budget, some quota still apply (unless you get us to raise them through a request).