# Possible to have a single instance running 24 hours and not use the free 28 hours on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using the Standard edition of Google App Engine and I am trying to get only a single instance to run for 24 hours without going idle and without exceeding the 28 free hours available for automatic scaling. I have tried a lot of adjustments but have not been successful in getting anywhere close. Even with the best adjustments to the various config parameters, I end up using about 2.5 instance hours per real hour. Has anyone had any success in getting this to work? It is also important that the instance never goes idle in order to provide users with a quick response. I am not interested in handling high traffic or long latencies. I'll deal with that incrementally as the the app becomes more used.

My app is written as microservices in Java and each service has a pretty fast response when API calls are made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, but only with a single-service app.  Each service gets its own instance so that is why you are using more.

Low volume apps can easily stay within the free quota with the default settings for a single-service app.

Comment: I that instance is running full-time it would also need to have a F1/B1 instance class, any other class will exceed the free quota.

Comment: I came across the docs that state: "Each service that you deploy to App Engine behaves like a microservice that independently scales based on how you configured it." - However, when you upload a version, the default version has its own configuration. I was under the impression that this was the only one used because in the admin console, it's the only one they show you when you click on the view link.